# Flutter Cloud Firestore - How to display current user display name when doc is equal to current user id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some code that saves the user's display name and uid to the cloud upon creating an account.  The code which manages this is here:

database.dart

```
Future<void> userSetup(String displayName) async {
  final CollectionReference users =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserNames');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
  users.doc(uid).set({'displayName': displayName, 'uid': uid});
  return;
}
```

However, I am confused about how to retrieve this data and display the display name as text on my profile page.  Here is part of the profile page:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('KIWI'),
      ),
      drawer: MainDrawer(),
      
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
                  radius: 60.0,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.photo_camera,
                    color: Palette.lightGreen,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,

//I want to display the username here

                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 400,
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    itemCount: 2,
                    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7),
                    onPageChanged: (int index) =>
                        setState(() => _index = index),
                    itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                      return Transform.scale(
                        scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 2,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          child: Center(
                            child: i == 0 ? HomeInfo() : Achieve(),
                            // this line
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `FutureBuilder()` but would recommend a state management solution managing more complex data on the UI.

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;   //
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;     //recommend declaring a reference outside the methods 

Future<String> getUserName() async {
  
  final CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('UserNames');
  
  final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;

  final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

  return result.doc.data()['displayName'];

}

UI:
  ...
       SizedBox(
         height: 20,
       ),
         FutureBuilder(
             future: getUserName(),
             builder: (_ , AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
             
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                  return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator());
             }
                 return Text(snapshot.data);
             },
         ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 60,
        ),
...
```

If the CircularProgressIndicator looks weird because its in the middle of the widgets, try wrapping the entire column with it instead.